# How to prevent summing up values of sub categories in matrix visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

In a matrix visual, if we drill up, the values for the sub categories are summed up for the larger category. However, this may not always be accurate for the larger category.

How do I prevent the summing up of these values of the sub categories?

I want to display the values for the subcategories and instead of summing up these values after drilling up, I want to  display the values for the larger category  by calculating based on the parameters for the larger category.

Please note that the value is a measure and it is being displayed in a matrix visual.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Since I am relatively new to stackoverflow, I may have made some mistake in framing the question. I could not detect it after going through the link. Kindly let me know so that I can edit the question.

Comment: This might help: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/clever-hierarchy-handling-in-dax/